Progress bar in splash screen api
can i show progress bar in splash screen API?
My Android application implements the splash screen API with a single activity. However I need to use a progress bar in the api splash screen to notify the user that there is data from the server being loaded. Can I use a progress bar?

Are you calling APi in the Splash Screen?  Seriously

yes i call the API data in the API splash screen then save it to the local android database

You can't add views like ProgressBar to Splash Screen API. It's designed to provide a consistent and minimal splash screen experience that quickly transitions to the main app content.
Instead, you can set animated icon in Splash screen and prevent Activity from being displayed until the data is loaded.
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val binding by lazy { ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) }
    private var keep = true

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val splashScreen = installSplashScreen()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        splashScreen.setKeepOnScreenCondition { keep }
        setContentView(binding.root)
        startLongRunningTask()
    }

    private fun startLongRunningTask() {
        Timer().schedule(5000) { keep = false } // wait 5 sec
    }
}

If you still want to use custom views like ProgressBar, you can transition from the system splash screen into your custom splash screen Activity. But Google recommends avoiding this scenario if possible and use the SplashScreen API to brand your splash screen. For more information, please refer to this link.

Thank you for the extraordinary answer. However, can I replace the progress bar with dialogue progress and keep using a splash screen fire with single activity?
I see several posts on the internet, it seems that dialogue progress does not need to make a custom UI to display progress dialogue.

@EkaAenunNisa keep using a splash screen fire with single activity, it seems ambiguous. Splash screen is dismissed as soon as your app draws its first frame if you don't use setKeepOnScreenCondition. UIs including ProgressBar, ProgressDialog won't be visible until the Splash screen is dismissed. If you want to show ProgressDialog after Splash screen, then yes, you can show it normally. But please note that ProgressDialog was deprecated since API level 26.

Sorry, I use google translate to translate my language to english.
Okay, now I understand. Can I show a fragment dialog after the splash screen API is finished and show a progress bar there? When the process of fetching data from the server is finished, the dialog will be closed. Can this be a good approach to keep using single Activity and splash screen API?

@EkaAenunNisa Yes, you can do it like this. It's the recommended approach by Google.
